# iPhone - Blinking Animation - Screen Refresh Rate Limits

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

From what I've researched online, the iPhone screen refresh rate is 60Hz (not sure if this applies to iPhone 6 as well) - meaning, it can refresh an image up to 60 times a second.

However, I have a project in which I need a very fast blinking animation - to animate a view back-and-forth (from visible to invisible), more than 60 times a second. I thought about using `CADisplayLink`, so I'll get called every time the screen refreshes, but unfortunately, as stated above, this is not fast enough (gets called 60 times a second only).

Is there something I'm missing here, or is there a way to achieve a higher blinking rate? Do iOS games achieve better rates than this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to achieve a faster display rate than the screen refresh itself, mainly because the screen can't refresh as fast, so people won't see it anyway.
Hence all iOS games are effectively vsynced at 60 fps.

That said, depending on what you're doing, you might not be getting 60 fps. Have you profiled your app to determine the fps it's running?
If it's not doing 50+, there's probably some optimization that you can do to get it as close to 60 as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've tried using CADDisplayLink just for a simple blinking animation (i.e. hide or show a view every time the screen refreshes) - but at that refresh rate, you can still see it's blinking (meaning, at that refresh rate the human eye can still see changes)